# How to get pixel-position of window.selection

Tags: javascript, image, dom-selection

I have been able to get the selection from the red box with this code:

```
 var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

Which returns a startOffset and a endOffset corresponding to the characters from 0-14 (in this picture) [image]

But how do you get the same kind of area-selection of a image? The desired output should be like the example below

[image]

Comment: Just get the position on the mouse event - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_clientx.asp

Comment: Or create an area tag to capture only that part when clicked. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp